# Which Org should be submitted for Security Review?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, security-review

We are planning to List our App in App Exchange.We have already created a developer account with the help of partner portal.We are currently in Security Review Step.Looking at the video it was mentioned that we have to submit the test org for Review and not the one in which Managed Package was created.

Out of the following, which one has to be submitted?

1. Does it mean we should create a test org from hub and **install** the managed package created from **developer account**?
2. Can we submit the **developer account with managed package** directly?
3. Should we move all the code created in developer account to test org and then submit the same for review?

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit the org in which you have **developed your managed package**. 
You need to give credentials of Other dev org just for testing(which they perform).

You don't have to move code anywhere.

All the best!!

Comment: Thank you Krishna,the one in which we are providing the credentials of dev Org for testing purpose should have the package installed??Am I right?

Comment: yes. We need to install.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to spin a new test org and install the package you want to get it reviewed for security review .

You don't want to be giving your developer org where all code resides because security review wants to actually see how a package looks when Installed in a subscriber org .

You do not need to move all the code to another org .The other org can just have a latest package installed .

> Also note that security review takes time (6 weeks apprx) and during that time you can continue working on feature update or fixing bugs without any interruptions if you do not submit your developer org

Comment: Thank you@Mohith,Just few more doubts                                                                                                       1)Then for which org should we submit the scanner reports?Test Org or Dev Org with Managed Package Created?
2)Should the test org  be a test/demo Org (Edition as Partner Enterprise) which is being created from hub??

Comment: Scanner reports can be from your dev org .The test org can be a Test from partner enterprise or a DE org which is not linked to a HUB .Hope that helps you

Comment: Yeah Sure,That was really helpful..